# Downloading a File on ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a serious Problem with Download in my ASP.net Project.
I used the same code in 2 pages to download a file :

```
   private bool DownloadAnhang_Tracking(string fileName, string filepath)
    {
        ////File Path and File Name
        string filePath = filepath;
        string downloadableFileName = fileName;
        System.IO.FileInfo filename;
        FileStream myFile;
        try
        {
            filename = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
            myFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            this.ShowErrorNotification("Fehler: " + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        ////Reads file as binary values
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(myFile);

        ////Check whether file exists in specified location
        if (filename.Exists)
        {
            try
            {
                long startBytes = 0;
                string lastUpdateTiemStamp =      File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(filePath).ToString("r");
                string encodedData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(downloadableFileName, Encoding.UTF8) + lastUpdateTiemStamp;

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = false;
                Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                Response.AppendHeader("ETag", "\"" + encodedData + "\"");
                Response.AppendHeader("Last-Modified", lastUpdateTiemStamp);
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename.Name);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (filename.Length - startBytes).ToString());
                Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                ////Send data
                binaryReader.BaseStream.Seek(startBytes, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                ////Dividing the data in 1024 bytes package
                int maxCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((filename.Length - startBytes + 0.0) / 1024);

                ////Download in block of 1024 bytes
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < maxCount && Response.IsClientConnected; i++)
                {
                    Response.BinaryWrite(binaryReader.ReadBytes(1024));
                    Response.Flush();
                }
                ////if blocks transfered not equals total number of blocks
                if (i < maxCount)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                Response.End();
                binaryReader.Close();
                myFile.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.ShowErrorNotification("Der Anhang wurde nicht gefunden!");
        }

        return false;
    }
```

So used this code in another page, but it doesn't work anymore! I pass the same information to the method but it doesn't work! The Error is from MSAjax:

> 0x800a139e - Runtime Error in JavaScript:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this
>   error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(),
>   response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

I don't get why this code works on page 1 but not on page 2.
Im using ASP.Net 4.5 WebForms with C#

Comment: Not too sure if it would be a problem, but is the download control inside an UpdatePanel by any chance?

Comment: I will look after it but no i got problems at recovering from my team foundation server, i look asap for it... May helped  Thanks!